# How to do a one-to-many join with conditions in posgreql

Tags: postgresql

Forgive me, I don't know how to ask this question and google for an answer. May have already been answered elsewhere on Stack, let me know if it is.

I want to use postgresql to join one table, Table A, with Table B such that the values in one set of columns in Table A are joined and multiplied (one-to-many join) by the corresponding values in a set of columns in Table B, based on whether the values in the set of columns in Table B are within the range of the values in the set of columns in Table A.

Basically:
Where Start_A >= Start_B AND End_A <= End_B

Like so:

[image: asdf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this can help you. But in your quest and result where you question "Basically: Where Start_A >= Start_B AND End_A <= End_B", I think this your mistake because in result i saw Start_A <= Start_B AND End_A >= End_B. And id write the query for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON startA <= startB
WHERE endA >= endB
```

Comment: Thanks xuan :)


Of course I feel silly, a Left join is a common thing.


I didn't think that this sort of thing would be common though.